# How can I lock the today() function in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Say I want to just capture the date at the moment when I input sth. to the spreadsheet. The [`TODAY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092984) function will capture the current date, but it will also automatically update itself tmr.

How could I make the [`TODAY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092984) function become a constant once the current time is captured?

Answer (score 6):

#### Answer:

*The `today()` function will always update every time you open the Sheet. In order to keep the date constant, you will either need to use an attached script, or using one of the keyboard shortcuts for Google Sheets.*

#### The Apps Script Method:

You can create a custom function which is attached to your sheet by following the `Extensions > Script editor` menu item. This will open a new window with a script editor in it. Here, you can create a function as follows:

```
function todaysDate() {
  var td = new Date();
  return (td.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + td.getDate() + "/" + td.getFullYear();
}
```

Save the script with the save icon, and go back to the Sheet.

You can now use this as a formula in your sheet - entering `=todaysDate()` in a cell will return the date in `MM/DD/YYYY` format.

- Example: `8/31/2020`.

**NB:** You can change the order of how the date is displayed by switching around the `td.getMonth() + 1`, `td.getDate(), and` td.getFullYear()`sections of the`return` line, depending on which format you wish to use.

#### The Keyboard Shortcuts Method:

As per the documentation on Google Sheets keyboard shortcuts:

- The specific shortcut for adding today's date to a cell is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd>.

  - Example: `8/31/2020`
- You can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd> to add the date *and* time.

  - Example: `8/31/2020 14:02:56`.

#### Things to note:

- You can see a list of keyboard shortcuts in Google Sheets by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> on Windows and Chrome OS, or <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> on Mac.
- Some shortcuts might not work for all languages or keyboards.
- You can see a full list of keyboard shortcuts [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/181110?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en&oco=1).

#### References:

- [Keyboard shortcuts for Google Sheets - Computer - Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/181110?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en&oco=1)
- [Custom functions in Google Sheets | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

Comment: I am from the UK... the MM/DD/YYYY format pains me... but it is sadly default :(

Comment: I'm from Finland, where the official standard is DD.MM.YYYY, yet I still always use ISO 8601 when I can.

Comment: Worked fine for a day, but after I opened the sheet the next day it got stuck on "Loading..." with an error message when hovering over it, and after editing the sheet, everything reloaded to the current date, not the locked-in dates.
(To test this I also added a get date and time function, which worked fine for the day, even if the file was closed and reopened, you see)

Comment: is it `apps script`? `Tools` does not show `Script editor`

Comment: @alper it's now `Extensions > Script editor` - Google has changed the UI since I wrote this answer. I've updated it for future readers

Answer (score 0):

I found a way around formatting so the date shows as it's formatted in my spreadsheet:

> 2 Feb 2022

Whenever I changed the order or removed the "/", it would return the following:

> 7/17/1905

Which is 42569 days away from today's actual date. So, I basically added that difference to it:

```
return (td.getDate() + td.getMonth() + td.getFullYear() + 42569);
```